# Kik | WhatsApp - Encrypted? iOS / Android Message encryption tips

Tags: encryption, android, ios, aes

Kik says that their client is using ssl etc. But it's kind of hard to tell if the messages is actually encrypted between the devices. What i can understand is that they don't got device-to-device encryption.

WhatsApp is it the same with.

Is there any other IM clients out there for the mobile phones that you really can trust on the encryption (aes256 or better) ?

I am looking for the best device-To-device encryption message app for iPhone & Android.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which Instant Messaging services use or allow secure protocols, and what do those protocols cover?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1634/which-instant-messaging-services-use-or-allow-secure-protocols-and-what-do-thos)

Comment: Nothing in that thread about any mobile clients.

Answer (score 1):

[Gibberbot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=info.guardianproject.otr.app.im#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDIxMiwiaW5mby5ndWFyZGlhbnByb2plY3Qub3RyLmFwcC5pbSJd) is made by the same project team that created Tor for Android. It's [opensource](https://github.com/guardianproject) so you can check out it's encryption and see if it satisfies you.

Comment: Is this the only alternative between a iOS & Android device? There must be some other options.